# connecting to sqlite with php

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I installed php on my local machine by installing XAMPP.

I have created php files that work fine,
and I have used the sqlite command line to create a database and insert data.

The problem is I can't seem to manage to use php to interact with the sqlite database.

I am new to both php and sqlite, so I used scripts I found on the internet.

I have tried using both the standard sqlite_open and the PDO methods, but both don't give me any output. neither positive nor error.

I read elsewhere to uncomment the php.ini files, nothing changed

Comment: Have you checked for any error message in the apache logs?

Comment: Linux, WIndows, Mac Os X ? PHP version ?

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use PDO (I suggest you to use it), you need to follow this steps:

1. Make sure you have PDO and SQLite Driver installed
2. Create a PDO Object with the correct DSN (Connnection String)
3. Create the statement: $stmt= $PDOObject->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE user_id = ?")
4. Set the fetch mode: $stmt->setFetchMode(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC)
5. Execute your query: $stmt->execute(array($user_id));

And then

```
while ($item = $stmt->fetch()){
//Some code
}
```

Comment: the DSN being something like 'sqlite:/path/to/database.sq3'